# What difference between AWS.S3.ManagedUpload() and s3.upload() methods?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

This is the link of information about of API AWS-sdk.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#constructor-property

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are basically the same thing. `s3.upload()` is a shortcut function that will use a `AWS.S3.ManagedUpload()` object to handle the file upload. You can achieve the same result as `s3.upload()` by building your own instance of `AWS.S3.ManagedUpload()` and calling the `send()` method on it.

Comment: which one is more better? which one provides more features and ease of use?

Comment: They are one and the same - see `upload` excerpt: `var uploader = new AWS.S3.ManagedUpload(options); if (typeof callback === 'function') uploader.send(callback); return uploader;`